# Single Send emails are not tracking to Sales Cloud from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud

As title says, I am having an issue as of 3 weeks ago in which my single-send emails are no longer reporting to Sales Cloud.

-I am using 18 digit contact ID as subcriber key like usual

-I have the box checked as usual

-I am sending from a SF DE

-My journeys are still tracking to the cloud

-Results of single sends are showing up in SFMC tracking folder, but I am not seeing them in the cloud

Support has been circular and unhelpful so wondering if anyone has seen this issue before.

Thank you